# FO on what mode: Multimode or monomode for 290mts

Tags: fiber

in your experience what's better to recommed for a friend?

Its to interconnect access level switches from two buildings.

Possible to interconnect to a ring topology on a near future.

Comment: You should recommend that your friend hire a cabling professional to give this advice. Your friend can get several cable vendors to survey and bid on the job. This is not something that amateurs should attempt.

Comment: It's *mutlimode* and *singlemode*. I don't know what "290mts" means.

Comment: At least tell us the distances involved.

Comment: @RonMaupin - spoken like a fierce defender of high profit margin cable contracting. Doing fiber well is entirely in the capacity of any "amateur" that cares to educate and equip themselves; and the educating and equipping will still leave lots of savings on the table .vs. most contractors when the job is done. There is no magical mystery to it.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Having been asked to try to fix many network problems that turn out to have nothing to do with the network equipment or configurations, but end up as cable problems, I leave that up to the professionals. There are some real concerns with cabling that pose real dangers, and the laws and ordinances concerning cabling are becoming more strict all the time. Failure to abide by these can result in large fines and get an entire building rendered as unfit to occupy until the problems are fixed. Low-voltage cabling is now comparable to power cabling from the perspective of regulation.

Answer (score 1):

For 290 meters, you can go either way.

In my personal experience I have found singlemode to be cheaper overall (despite potentially more expensive SFPs and connectors, the cable is MUCH cheaper than OM3 & OM4 multimode, and the connectors and SFPs can be cheaper as well under the right shopping conditions.) Singlemode is also not limited to 10 GB - the future capacity is virtually unlimited if and when faster optics become available, while OM3 can only do 10GB for 300 meters, which might not even work depending on the length of patchcords, etc at either end of a 290 meter (if that's accurate) link. OM4 will buy you some more distance, but neither has the future potential that singlemode does. Even if it's only getting lit at 1 GB **now**, experience says that upgrades will be wanted in the next 10 years, and not having to replace the cable makes those upgrades easier.

But lots of people would choose OM3/4 based merely on distance and a somewhat inaccurate in detail (or outdated) belief that "multimode is always cheaper."